Ruby - Creating hash from array not working
I'm trying to create a lookup table for a bunch of words, by using the sorted characters as keys and arrays of all the words with the same characters as keys.
My current code looks like this:
words = Hash.new(Array.new)
word_list.each do |word|
  words[word.chars.sort].append(word)
end

At the moment, it seems to be looping over the words properly but not adding anything to the words hash. What am I doing wrong?

To get different arrays for different keys, you have to assign the array from a proc, i.e. words = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }. Otherwise all keys would refer to the very same array.

Consider also using #each_with_object here:  words = word_list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |word, hsh| hsh[word.chars.sort].append(word) end
